# How do I allow CSS files to be referenced from other domains?

Tags: css, cross-domain, stylesheet

I set up two websites. One, http://static.example.com/, is hosting static files. Another one, http://www.example.com/ hosts a web application.

When, within http://www.example.com/, I reference images from the static site such as http://static.example.com/logo.png, the image is displayed correctly. However, when I put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.example.com/demo.css" />
```

on the page, the style from `demo.css` is not applied to the page.

In Chrome's Developer Tools:

- In *Network* tab, I can clearly see the `demo.css` file being requested and received (HTTP 200 or HTTP 304) by the browser. If open the file in the new tab, the CSS code is displayed correctly.
- In *Network* tab, when I click on the file and open *Response* sub-tab, it shows: *“This request has no response data available.”*
- In *Sources* tab, there is [static.example.com](http://static.example.com/) node and it contains `demo.css`, but when I click on `demo.css`, the panel at the right remains empty, as if the file was empty.

Is there a sort of cross-origin policy for CSS files?

If I replace the style file by, for instance, http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css, the one used by Stack Overflow, the style is applied to the page.

Notes:

- The CSS file `demo.css` contains just `body{color:red;}`. The HTML page  contains a body with a `<p>Hello, World!</p>` inside. The browser shows black text. I would expect it to show red text instead.
- I replaced the actual TLD by `example.com`, the actual structure and domain names are very similar.
- I can reproduce the issue with Chromium 49 and Firefox 45.

Comment: There is no cross-origin policy for css files. You should have no problems linking the css that way. There must be something else causing this issue.

Comment: could it be related to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4070? (scroll down to `CVE-ID: CVE-2010-0051`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be related to the `content-type`.

For the CSS file that doesn't work:

```
Content-Type:text/plain
```

For the CSS file that does work:

```
Content-Type:text/css
```

As noted in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#wikiArticle)

> Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded cross-origin:
>
> - CSS with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`. Due to the relaxed
>     syntax rules of CSS, cross-origin CSS requires a correct Content-Type
>     header. Restrictions vary by browser:
>     [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),
>     [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/2010/mfsa2010-46.html),
>     [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9877),
>     [Safari](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4070) (scroll down to
>     CVE-2010-0051) and [Opera](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/943/).

Look into the `Content-type` headers and ensure they're correct.